# How to prove axiomatically whether a function is a cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> **Definition 1**. Let $\operatorname{P}:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function such that
>
> - $\operatorname{P}(\emptyset)=0, \ \ \ \operatorname{P}(\Omega) = 1,$
> - $\operatorname{P}(A) \geq 0\ \ \ \forall A\in F,$
> - $$\operatorname{P}\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right) =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{P}(A_i)\ \ \ \text{for all events that are mutually exclusive}.$$
>
> The function $\operatorname{P}$ is then called the *probability function*. Here $F$ denotes the set of possible events.
>
> **Definition 2**. The function $F_X(x)$ is called a *probabability distribution function* if $$F_X(x)=\operatorname{P}\{X<x\}.$$

A probability distribution function can thus only be such if and only if it satifies the three axioms above. It is intuitive that we may check the first axioms as

$$\operatorname{P}(\emptyset)=0\iff\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}F_X(x)=0,\ \ \ \operatorname{P}(\Omega)=1\iff\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}F_X(x)=1.$$

Since we may show that

$$\operatorname{P}\{\alpha\leq X<\beta\}=F_X(\beta)-F_X(\alpha) \ \ \forall\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{R}:\beta>\alpha,$$

then

$$\operatorname{P}(A) \geq 0\ \ \ \forall A\in F\iff F_X(\beta)-F_X(\alpha)\geq0.$$

If the derivative exists, simply checking its nonnegativity suffices. At discontinuities we may apply one-sided limits. Discrete case requires special care.

---

### Question

- **How does one, in general, see if axiom $3$ is satisfied by some function $g(x)$?**

In other words, I am looking for a if-and-only-if condition which one can use to validate that $g(x)$ actually is a CDF. A (hint/link to the) proof of this condition would also be be great if it is not too much trouble. So far, I have been unable to come up with anything very useful. A combination of axioms $1$ through $3$ does give

$$0\leq F_X(x)\leq 1$$

but I do not think this condition and the conditions above are enough.

Comment: Just a detail, you should mention $F$ is a sigma-algebra or the set of possible events at least.

Comment: Any nondecreasing function which goes to zero at $-\infty$, goes to $1$ at $+\infty$, and is left-continuous is a distribution function under your definition.

Comment: Two followup remarks: 1. the more popular convention these days is to use $\leq$, not $<$, in the definition, in which case "left-continuous" becomes "right-continuous". But your definition is seen in places, for example in Russian literature. 2. It can happen that your probability space is "not rich enough" to implement certain distribution functions. For example, your space certainly must be uncountable in order to implement a continuous random variable.

Comment: @Ian Hmm, that's interesting to see! I think I am capable of proving (with the definition given here) that $F_X(x)$ is left-continuous but probably will need assistance in showing that the conditions you listed are necessary and sufficient. (I will give it a shot though.) It also looks like I have picked up the odd textbook that indeed uses $<$, yet since it behaved in an interesting manner (for me) in the discrete case, I went along with it.

Comment: @Ian Concerning the richness aspect: does this mean that one has to specify, to be rigorous, a certain probability space before applying the conditions? I haven't yet seen excercises that do this, but if so, I will certainly keep it in mind. --- If you write up an answer (with perhaps a link to the proof or an outline of it here), I will accept.

Comment: @LinearChristmas In practice one usually does just the opposite: without explicitly constructing it, you assume that your probability space is rich enough to do whatever you need. Usually in elementary probability this is taken for granted. Even in measure-theoretic probability, it doesn't need to be addressed explicitly very much, because most things can be done using relatively universal constructions.